# DC DC converter

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I am newbie trying to build a circuit, please help me out.
I am trying to build a DC-DC converter whose input will be 24V and output would be 5V 3A.
I have picked AP63301WU-7 DC DC converter from Diodes Inc.
As per the application circuit, I have to use two resistors 158Kohm and 30.1Kohm that act as a voltage divider at the Feedback pin.
The problem is I am unable to find a resistor that is rated to the required wattage (which will be 3A * 24V = 72W). The closest I could find has a power rating of 660mW. Is it fine to use this resistor?

Comment: A DC-DC converter (switcher, I'm assuming for now) should not require such a resistor! It should be very efficient as a buck converter. Can you link the datasheet?

Comment: https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/DIOD/DIOD-S-A0009645406/DIOD-S-A0009645406-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0

Comment: Total loss should be under 3 W. Efficiency around 84%. Those resistors are rather high valued, for divider purposes. So very little power dissipated in them. Low milliwatts, I expect. 5 V at 3 A will not require 3 A at 24 V!!! More likely closer to 0.75 A at 24 V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are feedback resistors that carry minuscule current. Any 0.1W resistor would do.

5V / (158K + 30K) = 0.00003A or 30uA

30uA * 5V = 0.15mW

Comment: Thank you for your answer!